# Do the vectors here span (0,y,z) despite the determinant being zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I had to show if $$(0,1,2), (0,2,3), (0,3,1)$$ span $${(0,y,z) } $$ 
where y,z belong to R.
I obtained the following set of equations where a,b,c are scalars. The solution can only be obtained if l set c=0. Otherwise l have 3 unknowns and 2 equations.

$$\begin{cases}
0+0+0=x \\ 
a+2b+3c=y \\ 
2a+3b+c=z
\end{cases}
$$

The determinant of the matrix below is also zero and in that case, there shouldn't be any solution for a,b,c.

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}   
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: 2(0,1,2) - (0,2,3) =(0,0,1) and 2(0,2,3) - 3(0,1,2) = (0,1,0).

Comment: @Pseudo , how about the determinant being zero ?

Comment: As someone below, determinant==0 only shows your 3 vectors are linearly Dependent. In here, this means you have infinite ways to construct (a,b,c). You can check this by represent a,b with 'c'. (=> There ARE solutions as much as 'number of possible c') // In equation, x should be 0 since your target space is.

Comment: @psuedo thanks, got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant being zero does *not* mean there are no solutions - it means that either there are no solutions, or there are infinitely many solutions (which is what we get here). Your system is consistent because we also have $x = 0$.

(A degenerate example is: would you say that
$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\end{smallmatrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ has no solutions?)

As someone mentioned in the comments, an easy way to proceed is to just show we have the two standard basis vectors spanning the $y$-$z$ plane -
$2(0, 1, 2) - (0, 2, 3) = (0, 0, 1)$ and $2(0, 2, 3) - 3(0, 1, 2) = (0, 1, 0)$.

Then any point $(0, y, z) = y(0, 1, 0) + z(0, 0, 1)$ and you can expand to get a linear combination of your spanning vectors.

An aside is that any two of your vectors already span, since they're pairwise linearly independent.

Comment: I haven't covered basis yet but l understand what you are saying. Alternatively, if l express a,b,c in terms of x,y,z. Would that be good enough too ?

Comment: @AristotleStagiritis yes, that's basically what my answer's getting at - when you have $(0, y, z) = y(0, 1, 0) + z(0, 0, 1)$ you can keep going to get $y[2(0, 2, 3) - 3(0, 1, 2)] + z[2(0, 1, 2) - (0, 2, 3)]$ to find $a, b$ (and just set $c = 0$). I've noticed that you do like to keep talking about $x$, even though $x = 0$ identically in this question.